# file uploading mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, shared-hosting, setup-deployment

I currently have an MVC project that I would like to upload to a file manager. I've already uploaded it to filezilla but my question is how do I get the website to read what I've uploaded. My host is no different than most. It is called bluehost. They have a file manager which expects folders and files which include .html and .php but they do not seem to be easily reading my cshtml files. Can anyone shed light on this subject. [picture of my file manager here if you need to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSte1.png)

Comment: `"which expects folders and files which include .html and .php"` - Well, does your host *support* ASP.NET MVC?  If they only support PHP then clearly you can't run an ASP.NET website there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Bluehost does not support ASP .NET or MVC.

Here's a post on their site for more reading:

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/197

Look into some other hosting options, such as GoDaddy. I have a site hosted with them right now and it is very easy to publish and deploy.